# Permission for getting Anonymous Statistics produced during usage of an IOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a Quiz Application for IOS platform. By using the number of wrong and right answers to the questions (accumulated on the device), I want to re-arrange difficulty levels for the questions. Can I directly send these anonymous statistics to my server on the cloud, or is it required to ask the users' permission on an App page?

Comment: Isn't that a matter between you and Apple?

Answer (score 0):

We submitted a few apps that took user's data anonymously and did not need to ask for any permissions.

As long as it is anonymous, when setting your app for submission on App Store Connect, you can select this option which says the data you collect does not link to the user's identity:

[image: App Store Connect User Permissions anonymous XCode iOS Swift]

The above is an example of `Product Interaction` but you can select No for the other sections as well if this is the case.

3 of these apps got accepted on the app store without issues.

**Update based on Cankan's comment**

> Is the device language of the user, sensitive information?

I believe yes as this seems to fall under `Other Diagnostic Data` and `Other Usage Data`.

It becomes a problem if you can trace the language back to a specific user, if you collect this anonymously, my original answer applies where you can select no.

Comment: Thank you. Is the device language of the user, sensitive information?

Comment: @CankanTulunay - please see my updates in the answer

Comment: Quiz questions will be related to Language Learning. For example; German speaking users answered xx times wrong and yy times right for the zzzTh question. I will not track any specific user and language tuple together.

Comment: If it's anonymous, it should be fine. We released one app: https://apps.apple.com/app/id1591725910 - here we only have guest users and we do collect language anonymously so that we can send the push notification in the correct language.